# Outlook - Linked Image can't be displayed

Tags: microsoft-outlook, office365

I have tried all the solutions provided by Microsoft but none of them work.

1. Modify BlockHTTPimages in registry (Don't have this in my registry)
2. Change Trust Center settings
3. Change Internet Options (Do not save encrypted pages to disk)

My organization is using an IMAP/SMTP server, but I don't think the issue is related to the server. This issue only occurs in the Outlook application. In the web version it works fine.

[Linked image can't be displayed](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TNaES.png)

Answer (score 1):

Based on my research, i find an [article](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/outlook/troubleshoot/message-body/https-linked-images-in-html-emails-show-red-x) about the error and it's suggested that you could try to change the below registry to check if there're any differences:
[image]

> Modify BlockHTTPimages in registry (Don't have this in my registry)

By the way, if you didn't find it, you can create it manually. References: [The Linked image cannot be displayed error in an Outlook email message](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-GB/outlook/troubleshoot/message-body/the-linked-image-cannot-be-displayed-error).

(It should be noted that if you modify the registry by mistake, serious problems may occur. Please [back up the registry](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/topic/how-to-back-up-and-restore-the-registry-in-windows-855140ad-e318-2a13-2829-d428a2ab0692) before operation.)

Comment: Just checking in to see if above information was helpful. If you have any further updates on this issue, please feel free to post back. If you think my reply is helpful to you, please remember to mark it as an answer. Warm thanks.